# What are the dimensions of the out-of-bag cumulative hazard function in a Random Survival Forest?

Tags: r, random-forest, survival-analysis

I'm using the `randomForestSRC` package in R to create a random survival forest.  I have 1276 patients and I'm using the default number of bootstraps which is 1000.  The dimensions of the out-of-bag cumulative hazard function are 1276 x 200.  Where is the 200 coming from?

```
rsf <- rfsrc(Surv(time, event) ~ PSA + BMI + race + age + 
                   SM + ECE + SVI + LNI + pG1 + pG2 + rpyear, data = uPenn)
rsf$chf.oob
```

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: You should also point out where you are getting a package named `rfsrc`. I don't see it in either the binaries or source packages on CRAN.

Comment: i believe the post refers to this package: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForestSRC/randomForestSRC.pdf